# Configuring a subdomain on nginx using namecheap

Tags: nginx, configuration, dns, subdomain

I bought a domain name using namecheap, for simplicities' sake lets' call it example.com.
I am running nginx on a Debian based VPS.

I want to set up the following configuration

- (www).example.com  points : to var/www/blog
- (www).static.example.com : points to
  var/www/static

However I can't wrap my head around configuring the subdomain using nginx, or is that something I need to do using Namecheaps control panel?

This is my configuration on Namecheap:

- @  111.111.111.111 Record type: A TTL: 1800
- www  example.com Record type: Cname/Alias TTL: 1800

No subdomains are configured, Should I configure subdomains here!?

And here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    root /var/www/blog;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name localhost example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
   }
}

server {
    root /var/www/static;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name static.example.com www.static.example.com;
    location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

However this leads to the following:

- www.example.com points to the correct destination
- random.example.com points to www.example.com (I don't want this to happen, it should return a 404)
- static.example.com gives me an error 400. If i look into my logs it can't find the file /var/www/blog/static/index.html, while actually I want it to point to /var/www/static/index.html

Comment: Yes, make a "static" subdomain in your DNS settings within Namecheap.

Comment: @Chris where should the "static" subdomain point to? Just to the IP address of my VPS and from there on nginx will figure it out?

Comment: Yep! You already added the "server" directive to capture static.example.com and point the request to the /var/ww/static directory. Fun fyi: so really anybody can point any subdomain to any server anywhere. But if the server owner doesn't add in the necessary directive in the configuration file and if you try to visit that subdomain (or domain) which isn't configured in nginx or Apache, then the browser will just say, "Can't find example.domain.com".

Comment: @Chris thanks! That solved my issue, I forgot to configure the subdomain in Namecheap.

Comment: @user3486416, hi, if my answer resolves the question, i would appreciate if you can click that accept button to mark this question solved, thanks!  (you'll also be getting some extra points for accepting an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that setting up DNS and configuring nginx are entirely different tasks.

The way I like to setup my DNS is to do a `CNAME` from `www` and other subdomains back to the original domain, if they are logically the same, and hosted on the same server.  (However, technically, it's incorrect, because it means that you specify that all of your domains have `MX` records, as well as `TXT` / `SPF` records showing that they could be used for mail.  But noone really cares, so, as long as you don't have your TLD itself as a `CNAME`, things should be fine.)

You don't see a `404` from `random.example.com` because the first `server` becomes your default server.  To avoid this, you might want to have an extra [`server`](http://nginx.org/r/server) context with a [`listen`](http://nginx.org/r/listen) directive having a `default_server` parameter, where you can unconditionally `return 404;` for all requests.

The reason your final `server` context might not be working may perhaps be due to a missing `listen` directive.  It usually helps to have an identical `listen` directive between all of your servers.

Comment: @laggingreflex, thanks for the bounty and the +1!  May I ask what was your issue?